# Copy range from google spreadsheet to google document

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to copy sheet contents with formatting to google doc? I need to fill doc template with table from spreadsheet like copy and paste. Or to convert sheet to doc with google app script.

Answer (score 1):

Open your files with `getFilesByName(name)`
With `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` you can get the data you want
And with `body.appendTable(rowsData)` you can and data to a table in a doc

Comment: It won't preserve formatting and joint cells I think

Comment: @s.kob He said "like copy and past"